# Grails 4 hot swap / recompile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grails

Im using:
Intellij
grailsVersion: 4.0.3
gorm.version: 7.0.4.RELEASE

I just get:
`Testcontroller.groovy changed, recompiling...`

But my code isn't hot deployed.
With Grails 3 everything worked fine.

What can I do so that the Controllers in Grails 4 and Spring Boot 2 get hot deployed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use spring-loaded (project has been idle for years but still works) or JRebel for "hot" reloads.

To enable:

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // Remove dev-tools from classpath
    // developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools") 
    agent "org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.8.RELEASE"
    // (Optional) Native OSX file watcher
    runtimeOnly "io.methvin:directory-watcher:0.9.6"
    //...
}
```

See: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/11441

Comment: This does not work for Grails 4.0.11 (latest as of today). Tested on a new empty app. Devtools works, but spring-loaded does nothing. Tried spring-loaded 1.2.8 and also 1.3.0, which [explicitly declares](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded#installation) it should work with Grails 4.0.4+. Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We found a solution for grails 4.0.13 similar to @erichelgeson

you found it here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11649#issuecomment-1085910706

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs(
        // javaagent: see
        // - https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11649
        // - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded
        // - find the jar here: https://repo.spring.io/ui/repos/tree/General/libs-snapshot-local/org/springframework/springloaded
        "-javaagent:libs/springloaded-1.3.0.BUILD-20210404.024037-2.jar",
        // ...
}
```

Here the links from the comment block:

- https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11649
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded
- find the jar here: https://repo.spring.io/ui/repos/tree/General/libs-snapshot-local/org/springframework/springloaded

Answer (score 1):

well solved forgot in build.gradle:

```
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
```

It's very slow compared to the old Spring boot but works as indeed.

Comment: There is an outstanding issue with that library: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11322