# Refreshing grails service class

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Let say I have a class `TotoService` in grails-app/services. Is there a way to refresh TotoService when grails is running?

Comment: Have you considered decoupling and using a separate microservice?

Comment: I use the Grails Multi-Project architecture like here https://guides.grails.org/grails-multi-project-build/guide/index.html (Section 3.1 Overview). The service is in the child plugin. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. Back to your q: do you mean `hot swap` as described: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61361479/grails-4-hot-swap-recompile ?

Comment: It is not exactly a hot swap. I want do an action so that when the war is deployed, I am able to refresh/restart a service or a child plugin with its configuration in grails-app/init/BootStrap.groovy and src/main/groovy/xxxxGrailsPlugin.groovy. Is it possible? Thanks for your replies.